# Why Ölberg and not Olivenberg?

Tags: etymology, place-name

I recently noticed that the German name for the Mount of Olives is *Ölberg*. I would give "Oil Mountain" as a gloss for this. This perturbs me; the meaning appears different from that of the English. (As far as I can tell, the meaning of both the French and Chinese equivalents is *Mount of Olives* and not something like *Mount of Oil*. I am not sure about other languages.) Moreover, it would appear that *Ölberg* also does not quite correspond to the Hebrew and Arabic names for the area (which German Wikipedia translates as *Olivenberg*). I would think that translations of names in European languages for Biblical places would be reasonably similar, since they should all stem from Greek or Hebrew.

Some searching has yielded a few instances where *Olivenberg* was used to denote the Mount of Olives, such as [this publication](https://books.google.com/books?id=B-I7AAAAcAAJ&lpg=RA1-PA63&ots=ozrXEtfSnS&dq=olivenberg%20jerusalem&pg=RA1-PA63#v=onepage&q&f=false) from 1828, [this German itinerary for a 2014 trip for Israel](http://www.uni-regensburg.de/theologie/medien/ws-13-14/programma_isra__l_2014_deutsch.pdf), and in a caption in [this article](http://www.wz.de/lokales/kreis-viersen/niederrhein/die-reise-nach-jerusalem-schwalmtaler-ordensschwester-veroeffentlicht-reisebericht-1.1295906) from 2013. However, the Luther Bible uses *Ölberg*, and it's also the name used by both [a Deutsche-Welle documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhY2PFX4teU) and [a 2011 *Spiegel* article](http://www.spiegel.de/reise/fernweh/oelberg-friedhof-in-israel-graeber-mit-aussicht-a-789920.html). A search for `olivenberg jerusalem` also gives far fewer results than `ölberg jerusalem` on Google.

Where does the name *Ölberg* come from? Is *Olivenberg* indeed much less common?

Comment: I never thought that Ölberg would be a mountain of oil because it's a fluid. When I hear that word I associate a hill with olives trees on it. But I don't know the cites where Ölberg is actually used.

Comment: @harper For what it's worth, by "Mount of Oil" I would have assumed some meaning like "the mountain where oil is produced" or something similar. Naturally, however, I'm not sure if this sort of thing would really carry over in German well.

Comment: So we have the same (or at least similar) impression. But this doesn’t suffice as an prove or answer.

Comment: Compare also "Weinberg" (vineyard).

Comment: Arguably this question belongs on Linguistics SE, not German SE.

Comment: in french it is"mont des oliviers" which translates to "mont of olives trees" so it is slightly different. I note that in german confused between a biological thing and the general category is common. For instance with "kraüter tee" which designate herbal infusions, which actually do not contain tea.

Comment: @Olivvv: thanks for the pointer. I'd forgotten that "olive" is used for the fruit for some reason. I suppose my main focus was also that it wasn't _mont d'huile_, which didn't help, in a way.

Comment: It does mean the mountain where oil is produced.  But oil two thousand years ago was not petroleum.  In the middle east it was olive oil.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The German *Ölberg* is a gravely wrong translation of the Greek name for the Mount of Olives *ὄρος τῶν ἐλαιῶν* (*oros ton elaion*). The Greek version is absolutely unambiguous when spoken, or written with accents. An ambiguity arises when using capital letters, as these don't allow for the placement of accents. The small-letter Greek writing system was finalised roughly in the 9th century, hence old Christian writings are bound to use capital letters. Accents where invented before the second century before common era, but not used mandatorily. Still, a native speaker, who had lived in the Mediterranean, could never succumb to such confusion.

When written without accents  *ΕΛΑΙΩΝ* is genitive plural of two lemmata, *ἐλαία* and *ἔλαιον* - thus it means both “of olives” and “of oils”. Accents are crucial to all varieties of Greek, old or modern, but are usually omitted in the old, capitalised form of writing.

[image]
[image]

In the tables above one of the lemmata bears the [circumflex accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex), called περισπωμένη in Greek!  Hence they are clearly different.  Perhaps Luther did not notice that, or his Greek was not very good. As the latter seems unlikely, another unlikely theory would be, that he used text in capital letters.

A translation similar to the German is used in Danish, Slovene and Finnish. Bulgarian and Russian simply use a cognate of the Greek word *elaion*. Most other languages – including Latin, its descendants and English – apparently took the other interpretation or translated directly from Hebrew.

Note that in many languages, words for “oil” (in the culinary sense especially) and “olive” have the same root.

> Arabic: *زيتون* / *زيت* (*zayt* / *zaytun*)
>   Greek: *έλαιο* / *ελιά* 
>   Spanish: *aceite* / *aceituna* (from Arabic)
>   Latin: *oleum* / *olea* (from Greek)
>   Maltese: *żejt* / *żebbuġ*
>   Serbo-Croatian, Bulgarian: *maslo* / *maslina*

So they are very intertwined concepts in the Mediterranean.

Likewise the various Germanic cognates of “oil” are from Latin *oleum* ‎(“olive oil”), from Ancient Greek *ἔλαιον* ‎(*élaion*, “olive oil”).

Later German, English and other languages lost the association of “oil” with olives, or perhaps the association was never so strong - north of the Alps, olives were very exotic in the past, and oil was associated with animal fats not plant fats.

> Während bei den Griechen und Römern das Olivenöl bereits in der Antike zum Braten und Verfeinern von Speisen üblich und die Butter nur für medizinische Zwecke eingesetzt wurde, dominierten in der deutschen Küche Butter, Schmalz und Fette noch bis ins frühe 20. Jahrhundert. In einem Bericht über die erste Fischereiausstellung in Wien (September 1902) beschreibt die Zeitschrift *Die Woche* vor allem französische Fischrezepte mit Olivenöl und klagt über die Speisefett-Versessenheit Zentraleuropas.

See: [ἐλαία](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%AF%CE%B1), [ἔλαιον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek), [زيت](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%AA), [זית](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%99%D7%AA#Hebrew)

The reconstructed proto-Germanic word for grease is [smerwą](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/smerw%C4%85), which yielded German [*Schmer*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schmer), English *smear* and Yiddish *שמיר*.

Common words for the oil that one should never ever eat in Russian, Turkish, Hebrew, Arabic etc derive from the Old Persian word [نفت](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%90%8E%B4%F0%90%8E%B3%F0%90%8E%AB#Old_Persian) (*naft*), cognate with the German scientific term *Naphtha* a.k.a. *Rohbenzin*.  In fact the [etymology of *Benzin*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=benzoin&allowed_in_frame=0) is also Arabic and interesting.

But nobody is calling the Mount of Olives *Schmerhaufen* or *Benzinspitz*.

Comment: In Hebrew oil (for cooking or lamps) is "שֶׁמֶן" not  "זַיִת".  It's ,הר הזיתים not השמנים

Comment: Re שמן connotations, thanks, updated.  Re הר הזיתים, yes, English, Latin etc are a translation of הר הזיתים.

Comment: Feel free to just edit directly

Comment: Accepting this since while the other answers were often also very helpful, I particularly liked the comment on the Greek here.

Comment: Thank you.  I hope someone who knows Ancient Greek will confirm it.

Comment: Addendum: I doubt that Luther's Greek may have been generally lousy, because great parts of his translation are very good. Theoretically, Luther might have used a bible in capital letters without accents, but I think it unlikely. I am a native speaker of Greek and proficient in many variants of old Greek. Particularly, Bible Greek is very easy for me. I can not imagine how one could think of oil instead of olives in this context. The other user's suggestion about Weinberg might point in the right direction.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding many small things I found useful and correcting some assessments about Greek. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Perfect.  Ευχαριστώ!

Answer (score 31):

Considering that another name for *Olivenbaum* is [*Ölbaum*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivenbaum) and the biological family is *Ölbaumgewächse* (Oleaceae), *Ölberg* with the meaning of “mountain of olive trees” makes sense to me.

*Ölberg* has nothing to do with (olive) oil, but with the tree itself.

Comment: Not exactly what I expected: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ölbaum%2BÖlbäume%2COlivenbaum%2BOlivenbäume&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28Ölbaum%20%2B%20Ölbäume%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28Olivenbaum%20%2B%20Olivenbäume%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 16):

I cannot prove the following, but would assume it makes sense.

The Lutherian bible was translated into German 1545 - Most probably no one in the intended audience would have had an idea what an "Olive" was supposed to be or would ever see one in his entire life (perhaps not even Luther himself).

Everyone, however, knew what "Öl" was (Albeit not made from olives).

Martin Luther intended to produce a text accessible and readable by *everyone*, so had to choose a wording that made sense to that audience.

An ngrams chart makes it pretty clear that "Olivenberg" never has been very popular:

[image]

Note Luther also used "Ölzweig" in the Noah story and not "Olivenzweig". The tree itself is called "Ölbaum" and the olive "Ölfrucht". So, absolutely nothing wrong here.

The Latin *olivum* means "olive oil" if I recall right - the tree is *olea* - You could thus even consider "Olivenberg" a wrong translation at Lutherian times, today "Olivenberg" would probably be understood as a large heap of olive fruit - Not the right thing either.

Comment: The German word *Öl* was derived from the Latin *oleum*, so it's natural to use it as its translation.

Answer (score 15):

As you can see from your examples, Öl is a more archaic usage. The substance known as "oil" was *originally* only derived from olives (which was constrained to the Mediterranean area in those days). Only later was it also applied to other fluids like what would be derived from wool, petroleum, sunflower seeds, etc.

So in the archaic usage, Öl would be pretty much synonymous with Oliven(baum). Keep in mind that language would often not strictly be literal, so it would not be strange to refer to a mountain where oil is produced, instead of the mountain where olive trees are grown. (This synonymous meaning goes back much further, into the latin, greek and possibly cretan).

From http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oil:

**Word Origin and History for oil**

n.

late 12c., "olive oil," from Anglo-French and Old North French olie, from Old French oile, uile "oil" (12c., Modern French huile), **from Latin oleum "oil, olive oil" (source of Spanish, Italian olio), from Greek elaion "olive tree," from elaia (see olive )**. Old English æle, Dutch olie, **German Öl**, etc. all are from Latin. It meant "olive oil" exclusively till c.1300, when meaning began to be extended to any fatty, greasy substance. Use for "petroleum" first recorded 1520s, but not common until 19c. The artist's oils (1660s), short for oil-color (1530s), are paints made by grinding pigment in oil.

For interest also consider e.g. Judges 9 verse 9.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, I never heard of or read *Olivenberg*.

I guess, that much of your bewilderment is based on an assumed relation to  mineral oil. A German Enyclopedia from 1894 states:

> Ölberg, im Alten und Neuen Testament, offenbar wegen seiner damals zahlreichen Ölbäume,...

translated:

> in the Old and New Testament, apparently due to its then numerous olive trees (German:*Ölbäume*)

Note, that *Ölbaum* is a significantly shorter synonym to *Olivenbaum*, and that the translations seems to derive directly from botanic *olea europaea*.

Comment: I'd thought of olive oil (since that seemed like the main way I could get a connection to "olives"), but still found it strange (since one would imagine that languages would separate "olive oil" and "olives").

Comment: see @tofro's answer: the distiction is there. Just that in (bible) German the fruit has the longer name: olive = Ölfrucht, and Öl in biblical context means olive oil. In everyday German you need to qualify that you mean olive oil - just Öl in food context means "sunflower or rape seed oil - I don't care which". It's like Nussbaum (literally nut tree) means a walnut tree, just like you're expected to know which type of nut a nut tree produces, you're expected to know which type of oil one gets from the Ölbaum (Olivenöl, not Baumöl).